# Specflow or BDDfy

Tags: .net, testing, bdd, specflow, acceptance-testing

I am looking to start using **BDD** in my next .NET project and I was wondering if anyone has experience using **Specflow** and **BDDfy** and which of the two they would recommend for a team that is new to BDD. This excersise will be a trial and if successful will become the BDD standard/best practice for future projects.

The team will be working with a QA and a BA, the BA will be responsible for writing user stories with the help of the QA. The QA might also help in writing the test stubs for the scenarios.

Comment: You may get much better answer to your opinion-based non-coding question on [Programmers Stack Exchange](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) site where questions about development methodologies and processes and quality assurance and testing are considered on-topic

Comment: Thanks @xmojmr I'll ask the question on "Programmers Stack Exchange"

Comment: @xmojmr **[Please stop using Programmers.SE as your toilet bowl](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73382/please-stop-using-programmers-se-as-your-toilet-bowl)**. See http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6487#6487

Comment: Dear @gnat, the link I gave to OP pointing to "Programmers" leads to the site's on-topic page. My advice was not to cross-post the question as-is without doing any research... Besides the technology decision/recommendation OP wants to know how to setup a team (and the processes) of QA and BA for their pilot project in Behavior Driven Development methodology. That's not appropriate for Stack Overflow, while Programmers claims to accept/solve problems of this kind. What would be the correct next step from your perspective except flushing OP down the toilet?

Comment: "What are your experiences with..." seldom make good questions, because they don't contain a problem statement or establish any objective criteria for evaluation.

Comment: @xmojmr - Programmers does not claim to accept or solve problems of this kind.  I think that's where the error is in your logic.  Some questions simply aren't a good fit for the Stack Exchange Q&A format.  Doesn't mean the question is bad; just that it doesn't fit.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion Specflow has a very good tool support and integration in Visual Studio. This help your developers and QA on the task of automation. But I like the simplicity of BDDfy more, as I don't need to replicate steps with a regex in the test class.

I think the main benefit of BDD is to define requirements collaboratively with techniques such as specification workshops or three amigos. This is strongly emphasized by another way to look on BDD, [Specification by Example (SbE)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specification_by_example). Thus, when starting with SbE some teams only create examples, but [don't automated](http://lizkeogh.com/2011/03/04/step-away-from-the-tools/), until you have enough experience and a well working specification workflow.

Have you thought about using a tool that is specialized on collaboration and business understandable inputs such as [FitNesse](http://fitnesse.org/) or [Concordion.NET](http://concordion.org/dotnet/)?